Does Blender has any shader node that same as ddx() in HLSL?
I'm using Blender4.0 and try convert some unity shader code to blender shader nodes,and there are some code like:
half d = ddx(input.normalWorldSpace.x);

An explanation of HLSL ddx()
After researching, I couldn't find any similar node in Blender. So, I'm wondering if there is a method to implement ddx() in Blender.
I'm appreciate for any reply.

Blender supports(sort of) OSL (which personally I have absolutely no knowledge about) Might it be it has something similar to what you are after?

Thanks but my project is using EEVEE cause of its faster render speed, the OSL is only supported on CYCLES as I know

You should really provide all this relevant information and context in the question in general as people may waste a lot of their time on a long and detailed answer without knowing your requirements. I don't think it's a high risk in this case though, because it seems there is no solution for this. But I might be wrong. It's still a good idea to provide as much info and context about your problem as possible.

I tagged EEVEE. As far as I know that's not possible and no functionality for this exists, but hopefully somebody knows more than I do and may be able to help.
